# DataTemplate with array of strings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate, contentpresenter

I have a `ContentPresenter` which takes a values with two types `string` and `string[]`. How to make visual view, based on value type.

My XAML code looks like

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Value}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String[]}">
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="???" ItemsSource="{???}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Also, need some way to receive selected item.

For a `string` value, code looks:

```
public class Text
{
    string Value { set; get; }
}
```

And, for a `string[]`

```
public class Combo
{
    string Value { set; get; }
    string[] Items { set; get; }
}
```

This code work fine only for `string` type. I don't know how to do it for `string[]`.

Comment: did you try DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}"

Comment: Sure, it works only for `string` type not for `string[]`(array) type, also I try `DataType="{x:Type System:Array}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `DataTemplate`s for `Text` and `Combo` type like:

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Text}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Combo}">
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Value}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I to do some changes with `ContentPresenter` ?

Comment: Yes, the Content you will bind on ContentPresenter should be of type Text or Combo.